# Evalutation strategy

Tags: evaluation

This example code:

```
f[A_, B_] := Eigensystem[{{A, B}, {A + B, A - B}}]
CodeBlock := {A = Ain; B = Bin; f[A, B]}
With[{Ain = 1, Bin = 2}, CodeBlock]
With[{Ain = 1, Bin = 2}, Evaluate[CodeBlock]]
```

gives this output:

```
{{{1/2 (2 Ain - Bin - Sqrt[Bin] Sqrt[4 Ain + 5 Bin]), 
1/2 (2 Ain - Bin + Sqrt[Bin] Sqrt[4 Ain + 5 Bin])}, {{-((-Bin + 
  Sqrt[Bin] Sqrt[4 Ain + 5 Bin])/(2 (Ain + Bin))), 
1}, {-((-Bin - Sqrt[Bin] Sqrt[4 Ain + 5 Bin])/(2 (Ain + Bin))), 
1}}}}

{{{-Sqrt[7], Sqrt[7]}, {{1/6 (2 - 2 Sqrt[7]), 1}, {1/6 (2 + 2 Sqrt[7]), 1}}}}
```

This shows that, firstly `Eigensystem` does the symbolic calculation, then the local values of `With` is plugged into the result expression. This can be slow when the matrix is large. I want the local values to be "eagerly" plugged so `Eigensystem` will go the numerical way. How to realize that?

Maybe my coding style of using a code block is bad, which leads to this problem. What is a good style then that can solve this and meanwhile still have the similar convenience of calling a large block of codes?

This issue is not just with `With`, but also all the other local-variable functions like `Manipulate`. I am not sure whether functions like `Table` have this issue too, since the result expression always gets evaluated.

Comment: I believe you want `Block` rather than `With`. For instance, `Block[{A = 1, B = 2}, f[A, B]]`. If you `Trace` the evaluation, you will see that the numbers get plugged in before it finds the `Eigensystem`. Of course, it's still doing it symbolically. To force it do it numerically, do `A = 1.`, for instance. I think you can also do `f[A = 1, B = 2]` if you would like to simultaneously set the values of `A` and `B`. As for the rest of the stuff, I'm not sure.

Comment: @march Great! Now I see the difference. Thanks.

Comment: Definitely check out [What are the use cases for different scoping constructs?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs).

Comment: By the way: it's preferable not to start your variable and function names with an uppercase letter to avoid conflicts with built in names. Your `Bin` is already dangerously close to such a conflict.